# How to concurrently write and read CUDA array with unique incrementing values?

Tags: cuda

I have a shared memory array initialized as follows

```
#define UNDEFINED 0xffffffff
#define DEFINED   0xfffffffe

__shared__ unsigned int array[100];
__shared__ count;

// We have enough threads: blockDim.x > 100
array[threadIdx.x] = UNDEFINED;


// Initialize count
if (threadIdx.x == 0)
  count = 0;
```

The threads have random access to `array`.  When a thread access `array`, if it is `UNDEFINED`, it must write a unique value, `count`, to that element, and then read that value.  If the array element is `DEFINED` or already has a unique value, it must just read the unique value out.  The tricky part is that `array` and `count` must both be updated by only 1 thread. Atomic functions only update 1 variable not 2.  Here's the method that I finally came up with for 1 thread to update both variables while blocking the other threads until it is done.

```
value = atomicCAS(&array[randomIndex], UNDEFINED, DEFINED);
if (value == UNDEFINED) {
    value = atomicAdd(&count, 1);
    array[randomIndex] = value;
} 

// For case that value == DEFINED_SOURCe, wait for memory
// writes, then store value
__threadfence_block();
value = array[randomSource];
```

There is some tricky concurrency going on here.  I'm not sure that this will work for all cases.  Are there better suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, the only time an `array` element will be written to is if it contains the value `UNDEFINED`.  We can leverage this.

1. A thread will first do an `atomicCAS` [operation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas) on the desired `array` element.  The `atomicCAS` will be configured to check for the `UNDEFINED` value.  If it is present, it will replace it with `DEFINED`.  If it is not present, it will not replace it.
2. Based on the return result from `atomicCAS`, the thread will know if the array element contained `UNDEFINED` or not.  If it did, then the return result from the `atomicCAS` will be `UNDEFINED`, and the thread will then go and retrieve the desired unique value from `count`, and use that to modify the `DEFINED` value to the desired unique value.

we can do this in one line of code:

```
// assume idx contains the desired offset into array
if (atomicCAS(array+idx, UNDEFINED, DEFINED) == UNDEFINED) array[idx]=atomicAdd(&count, 1);
```

A more complete code could be like this:

```
value = DEFINED;
while (value == DEFINED){
  value = atomicCAS(&array[randomIndex], UNDEFINED, DEFINED);
  if (value == UNDEFINED) {
    value = atomicAdd(&count, 1);
    array[randomIndex] = value;}
  }

 // value now contains the unique value, 
 // either that was already present in array[randomIndex] 
 // or the value that was just written there
```

Comment: Getting closer to the solution.  But there might still be a problem.  

If 2 threads access that statement at the same time with the same idx value, then after the atomicCAS operation the first one has set array+idx to DEFINED, and after that blocking operation, the second one finds array+idx == DEFINED.  The second thread isn't guaranteed to get the count value.  

In CUDA we may write that as one statement, but the compiler breaks that down into multiple instructions.

Comment: The __threadfence_block(); value = array[idx]; statements are still needed afterwards.

Comment: If a thread reads a value of `DEFINED` then it knows it must read that location again.  And yes, you should mark the `array` as `volatile`, then you don't need any threadfence (although atomics are guaranteed to return an actual value, not a cached or optimized value).  Since you haven't provided anything like a complete code (your code is not even compilable) I'm not trying to make a complete worked solution for you.

Comment: The while loop is a nice addition to avoid the __threadfence_block().  At the end of the while loop (and after the if statement, you still need to add value = array[randomIndex];  That allows a thread that is only doing a read to get the count value from the array.  Otherwise the read-value would be DEFINED.

Comment: I added a volatile keyword to the array declaration.  The compiler then errored out with an incompatible type error on the atomicCAS call unless I made an explicit cast:  value = atomicCAS((unsigned int *)&array[randomIndex], UNDEFINED, DEFINED);

Comment: Robert Crovella, thanks for your thoughts and ideas on this.  They have been very helpful.

Comment: I don't agree with this:  " Otherwise the read-value would be DEFINED."  A thread cannot exit the while loop with `value==DEFINED`.

Comment: I was writing a rebuttal, but then thought about it more deeply and realized that you are right.  There is no need for the value = array[randomIndex], the atomicCAS will make that assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For have an array of incrementing values, use  **prefx-sum**  also called **scan** algorithms,  based on binary tree ower threads. First over local block(shared memory in the name) ? then global over blocks, then add each summ back to each block. 
Also it may be efficient for each  **block**   to read not one but some values, what are equal of physically "warp size" like 16 int values for example ( i apologize, because i have done this things long time ago and  don't know  proper sizes and proper names for this things in CUDA).
Ahh, btw,the final values, in case of equal incrementing, could be retrieved as the function from local or global thread.id, so you do not need scan at all

Comment: I'm not trying to keep a running sum.  I'm simply trying to write unique incrementing values to randomly and concurrently accessed arrays.  And if that unique value is already written to that element, to just read it out.

Comment: if all threads in block would do different stuff, this would  be much slower then on normal processor, especially modern 4-cores, whatever.
Howewer if you do want, look at the full list of CUDA atomic operations, i would look something about XOR, whatever.Also as i remember there is kind of semafores in CUDA to block thread.