# CUDA C++ shared memory and if-condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, cuda

i have a question i couldnt find an answer to myself, and i was hoping some of you could offer me some insight regarding a possible solution. Within a kernel call, i would like to insert an if-condition regarding access to shared memory.

```
__global__ void GridFillGPU (int * gridGLOB, int n) {
    __shared__ int grid[SIZE] // ... initialized to zero
    int tid = threadIdx.x
        if (tid < n) {
            for ( int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) { 
                if (grid[k] == 0) {
                    grid[k] = tid+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    //... here write grid to global memory gridGLOB
    }
```

The idea is that, if the element grid[k] has already been written by one thread (with the index tid), it should not be written by another one. My question is: can this even be done in parallel ? Since all parallel threads perform the same for-loop, how can i be sure that the if-condition is evaluated correctly? I am guessing this will lead to certain race-conditions. I am quite new to Cuda, so i hope this question is not stupid. I know that grid needs to be in shared memory, and that one should avoid if-statements, but i find no other way around at the moment. 
I am thankful for any help

EDIT: here is the explicit version, which explains why the array is called grid

```
__global__ void GridFillGPU (int * pos, int * gridGLOB, int n) {
    __shared__ int grid[SIZE*7] // ... initialized to zero
    int tid = threadIdx.x
        if (tid < n) {
        int jmin = pos[tid] - 3;
        int jmax = pos[tid] + 3;
          for ( int j = jmin; j <= jmax; j++ { 
            for ( int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) { 
                if (grid[(j-jmin)*SIZE + k] == 0) {
                    grid[(j-jmin)*SIZE + k] = tid+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } //... here write grid to global memory gridGLOB
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the code. `grid` is never initialised anywhere I can see, so I don't see how that could work. But leaving that aside, yes, as written, you have a memory race.

Comment: the initialization of `grid` is in the second line. I am new to CUDA and thought thats how you initialize an array which all threads can access

Comment: Initialisation mean "give an initial value". You test for `grid[k]==0`, but before that, `grid` is never given a value.

Comment: as far as i know shared memory is always initialized as 0. Maybe i am wrong, in that case you would need to set the values to 0 first of course. EDIT: you are right, it needs to be set to zero first, i will correct

Comment: That is my point. Shared memory *isn't* intialised (in C++ no local scope arrays are initialised to anything by default)

Comment: OK, so now you have illegal initialisation for the shared memory. That isn't valid syntax in CUDA

Comment: i realized that while trying to run it. it is the first time i use shared memory, so i will need to see how to initialize it. Edited

Comment: For the problem that you described in your question, the answer is to use `atomicCAS(grid[(j-jmin)*SIZE + k],0,tid)`. However, I doubt that this is the answer to your real problem. (Aside from the obvious problem that you should not compare to `0` because `tid` might be `0`.)

Comment: i forgot the +1, my bad. i will read into atomicCAS implementation and post an answer if i find one

Comment: As @havogt said, you should be able to make something work with `atomicCAS`.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818003/how-to-concurrently-write-and-read-cuda-array-with-unique-incrementing-values) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should model you problem in a way you don't need to worry about "if has been written already", also because cuda offers no guarantee in the order in which thread will be executed, so the order might not be the way you excpect. 
There are some minor things that cuda ensure you order wise within a warp but that is not the case.
There are sync barries and stuff you can use but I don't think is your case.

if you are processing a grid you should model that in a way that each thread has its own region of memory is going to work on. and that should not overlap with other thread region (at least in writing, in reading you can go outside boundaries). Also I would not worry about shared memory, make the algorithm works first, then think about optimization like load a tile in shared memory using the warp.

In that case if you want to split your domain in a grid you should setup the kernel, in order to have enough threads as your grid "cells" or pixels if is an image. Then you use the thread and block coordinates that cuda provides you to compute where you should read and write in memory.

There is a really good course on udacity.com about cuda, you might want to have a look at that.
https://www.udacity.com/courses/cs344
There is also another one on coursera.com but I don't know if it is open right now.
Anyway dividing the domain in a grid is a really common and solved problem ,you can find a lot of material on that.

Comment: i agree on the shared memory aspect which might not be needed at this point. But the overlap of thread regions is hard to avoid for my special problem. I will look into the provided material. Thanks!

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about your problem?.
Also other thing you can do is model the problem in a "odd/even" tiles.
Is just an idea, you can shut down  tiles,in order to avoid the overlap, kinda like a checker board, and you run the kernel twice , first on the "white" checker then on the black ones. But before going down that road I would make 100% sure the algorithm is not parallelizable the way you want.
You said it is modeled as a grid right? Is it a scatter or gather kind of algorithm?
PS: you have also atomic operation that can help you.

Comment: the idea is to flood the `grid` (representing a certain position in space) with particle indexes `tid`. this position can be flooded with maximum `SIZE` indexes, and once  a grid element has been written, another `tid` cannot be at position `k`, but only in a "vacant" spot, that is the next one `k+1`

Comment: Now I understand, so basically you wanted to check if the index at the grid position using a control value, maybe -1?
If that the case you can pre-fill the shared memory in parallel, by letting each thread write to the memory location the -1, and then, use a synchronization barrier.
This is a common technique to load memory into shared memory.
The coursera coures I mentioned does tiled matrix multiplication that covers those technique that might be useful for you

Comment: i read a bit about synchronization barriers, especially the `_syncthreads()` option. I am also aware of `atomicAdd()`, which brought me to use shared memory in the first place. But in this case, my guess is that it is not the right thing to do, because it is the if-condition that needs to be synchronized. I will read into it , thx!

Comment: what i mean is: the `if`-condition (which is checked in a thread) needs to be synchronized with the write (which occurs in another thread where the if-condition has already returned `true`).

Comment: `atomicCAS`was the solution to my problem Thx to everyone!